# How to use regular expression to match specific digits and mutate conditionally? (R)

Tags: r

I am trying to build a mutate with regular expression to identify specific digit matches, and then assign a new value to a new column `var2` depending on a specific priority ranking.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- tibble(var1 = c("1", "10", "1-10", "1-2-4-5"))
```

- If any value contains 1, assign 1 to var2
- If any value contains 2, assign 2 to var2
- If any value contains 3 to 10, assign 3 to var2

```
df_desire <- tibble(var1 = c("1", "10", "1-10", "1-2-4-5"), var2 = c(1, 3, 1, 1))
```

I'm expecting to use `mutate`, `case_when`, and `str_detect`.

```
df_output <- df %>% 
  mutate(
    var2 = case_when(
      str_detect(var1, "[1]") ~ 1, 
      str_detect(var1, "[2]") ~ 2,
      str_detect(var1, "[3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10]") ~ 3,
TRUE ~ 0))
```

Using that code returns 1 when var1 = 1, but also when var1 = 10 whereas I want it to be 3. How should I adjust my code to get my desired output?

Comment: @akrun Thanks for catching the typo. For the last row ("1-2-4-5"), it should indeed be 1; I have corrected my post. For the third row ("1-10"), it would match 1 (as `var1 = 1`) and also match 3 (as `var1 = 10`). However, 1 is considered a higher priority than 3, so it would ultimately get assigned 1 instead of 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will be partial matches if we don't use word boundary.  An option is to use `separate_rows` and then create the column

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
  separate_rows(var1, convert = TRUE) %>% 
  group_by(rn) %>% 
  summarise(var2 = case_when(1 %in% var1 ~ 1, 2 %in% var1 ~ 2,
        any(3:10 %in% var1) ~ 3, TRUE ~ 0)) %>%
  select(-rn) %>%
  bind_cols(df, .)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 × 2
  var1     var2
  <chr>   <dbl>
1 1           1
2 10          3
3 1-10        1
4 1-2-4-5     1
```

---

Or if we want to use `str_detect` - use the expression with the priority in the same order in `case_when`

```
library(stringr)
df %>% 
  mutate(var2 = case_when(str_detect(var1, "\\b1\\b") ~ 1,
      str_detect(var1, "\\b2\\b") ~ 2,
      str_detect(var1, "\\b[3-9]\\b|\\b10\\b") ~ 3, TRUE ~ 0))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 × 2
  var1     var2
  <chr>   <dbl>
1 1           1
2 10          3
3 1-10        1
4 1-2-4-5     1
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
sapply(strsplit(df$var1, '-'), \(x) 
    na.omit(match(1:3, replace(x, 3:10, 3)))[1])
[1] 1 3 1 1
```